# Instrumenting - VIewctrollers not removed from memory after pop to root VC

Tags: ios, swift, profiling, instruments

I am doing instrumenting for my app, and When I check all the view controllers and objects still on memory.
Even though its been called Pop to root view controller for the Navigation stack.

Please help me do we need to add any other special code to remove from memory?

### **Modified  : Updated Code snippet**

```
func parseFeatureDetailsInsertIntoDB (featureArray featureArray : NSArray)   {
    let entityArray = NSMutableArray()
    for i in 0 ..< featureArray.count {
        let dict = featureArray[i] as! NSMutableDictionary
        let featureEntity =  FeaturesEntity(dict: dict)
        entityArray .addObject(featureEntity)
    }
    // insert into DB
    DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.insertFeatureDetails(model: "", variant: "", featureArray: entityArray)
    entityArray.removeAllObjects()
}
```

Comment: No you don't - there's probably something wrong with your code. You should add it here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for code retaining your viewcontrollers. 
You are probably having a retain cycle.

Comment: Its Return in Swift with ARC.. not sure how the retain cycle is maintaing

Comment: @Bharathi you still can have a retain cycles in swift with ARC. Can you please show us your code?

Comment: I have added the code on the question.. In this the Enitity which i am adding in to array was not removed from the  Memory when i am doing profiling